# How do I revert sudo sysctl -w kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1?

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, security, sysctl

I did this in order to execute "brave browser" in my new debian installation.

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1
```

I've read this maybe a potential risk for my machine security how do I revert this command?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

By simply setting it to 0 again:

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=0
```